# Segmentation fault when checking if (char == '\n')

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, getchar

I have been struggling with this for over an hour now and I can't seem to find out why I get this error.

```
int  inp, count;
char numBuff[21];

count = 0;
while((inp=getchar()) != EOF) { // get Value (last field)
    printf("input is '%c'\n", inp);
    if (inp == '\n') break;
    if (inp == ' ') {
        continue;
    }
    numBuff[count++] = inp;
    printf("go back through loop\n");
}
printf("Out!");
numBuff[count] = '\0';
```

if I input 1013 I get the following

```
input is '1'
go back through loop
input is '0'
go back through loop
input is '1'
go back through loop
input is '3'
go back through loop
input is '
'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The only thing I can gather from this is that it is failing when I check if inp == '\n' but why?  I moved the go back through loop printf to just after the check if inp == '\n' and it never reached that one either so I know that it is occurring there.

Comment: Where do you initialize `count` to `0`?

Comment: `%c` is for characters, `inp` is an `int`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I do it right above the loop but I messed up on my copy/paste

Comment: Although probably not the cause of your crash, `numbuff` is an array of 21 characters, yet you never check that `count` is in the range `0..20`.

Comment: It's a known input that will never be larger than 20 characters but I see your point.

Comment: @David Schwartz I was hopeful when you mentioned inp was an int so I changed it to a char but unfortunately, still the same issue.

Comment: @Geoff You should keep it as int if checking for EOF, cast it when passed to printf instead.

Comment: Is there any more code below the last line? The `printf("Out!")` is not necessarily printed where you expect because of standard output line buffering.

Comment: just a return statement "return 1"

Comment: @Geoff And what follows in the function you return to, or is this the `main` function of the program? If not, try putting `printf("Returned\n");` right after you call this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *gather* that the error is in the loop, but how do you know? Did you try using a debugger - a useful tool that will help pinpoint where a crash occurs and allow you to examine the state of your program.

Dollars to donuts the crash occurs in code *after* the loop. The reason you do not see the "Out" message is because you don't print a newline so the standard library buffers the output.

Comment: I haven't learned how to use debuggers yet, that's next weeks agenda at school.

Comment: Wow, amazing, it was happening outside of this loop, outside of the function entirely.  There was a function call later in my main that was the actual problem.  So you were right, it wasn't printing "Out!".  Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember - debugging is a lot easier if you don't blindly rely on assumptions but verify them. And realizing that when you eliminate the impossible what remains, however improbable, must be the truth.

Comment: Occam's cutting tool to the rescue yet again :)

Answer (score 6):

`count` is uninitialized which is used as array index. Initialize it to 0.

Comment: I mentioned above in my comment that I do initialize count to 0 but I forgot to paste it in here.  I will edit it.

Comment: @Geoff I do not see any other problems with your code. Though you should use %d if you want to print an int and check not to overflow the buffer `numBuff`. But those are not the issues for your input. See here: http://ideone.com/TRfk6W  I suspect that you do something else after the loop that's causing the problem. What's the rest of the look like?